# Iphone videos for Court

Tags: iphone, ipad, video

I have some iphone videos that my atty has told me I need to put on or in something that can be handed to a judge for a civil matter. I originally was just gonna email them or put them on a flash drive but he said that isn't sufficient for court.

Pictures and documents I'm printing & putting in a binder... the videos I'm a bit stumped stumped for ideas. The best I've been able to think of is getting a cheap old laptop (with a decent battery so it doesn't die in court) and put the videos on the desktop of the laptop to be played/replayed on a decent sized screen as needed. Any other ideas? I feel like there has to be a better way but maybe my mind wants technology to be better then it is at the moment. I don't want to get so fancy that judge or whomever has trouble figuring out how to play the videos - just want it simple as possible.

I have enough work/personal stuff on my own devices I don't want to just handover what I already own loaded up with personal stuff not related to the matter. 
My attorney is not tech savy, he doesn't email or text, only does phone calls so he has no advice on how.

Comment: Ask at the court

Answer (score 2):

Burn the videos to DVD, so they can be played in a regular DVD player. Also hand over all data files on a USB drive.